# Add item at top of multi column listbox

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I found some information about insert function but it seems to be not available in Excel VBA.

I create a FOR which will move each row to +1 position and then insert item at 0 index.

Is there an easier way to add an item at the beginning of a multi column listbox?

My version looks like this:

```
Sub InsertRecordAtTheTop(sText1, sText2)
    Dim i
    With lbCases
        If .ListCount > -1 Then
            .AddItem "0" ''' add new row
            For i = .ListCount - 1 To 1 Step -1 ''' move everything +1 postion
                .List(i, 0) = .List(i - 1, 0)
                .List(i, 1) = .List(i - 1, 1)
                .List(i, 2) = .List(i - 1, 2)
                .List(i, 3) = .List(i - 1, 3)
                .List(i, 4) = .List(i - 1, 4)
            Next i
            .List(0, 0) = sText1 ''' paste new values at top
            .List(0, 1) = sText2
            .List(0, 2) = ""
            .List(0, 3) = ""
            .List(0, 4) = ""
        Else
            .AddItem sText1 ''' if listbox is empty, just paste
            .List(0, 1) = sText2
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AddItem` takes an optional parameter to specify the index position. By default it adds to the end. If you specify 0 it will add at the beginning. Try Something like:

```
.AddItem "Some Text", 0
```

More information can be found in this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835328(v=office.15).aspx) article.