# Add item to the beginning of my ComboBox?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I'm trying to add items at the top of a ComboBox.

I've tried this:

```
iCount = 1
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Range("A2").Select
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        If ActiveCell.Value = ComboBox1.Value And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17) <> "" Then
            ComboBox3.AddItem
            ComboBox3.List(iCount - 1, 0) = (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2))
            iCount = iCount + 1
        End If
        If ActiveCell.Value = "ANY" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17) <> "" Then
            ComboBox3.AddItem
            ComboBox3.List(iCount - 1, 0) = (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2))
            iCount = iCount + 1
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End With
```

Using this code, the items are added regardless of their order in the ComboBox.

I've also tried to create two `Do Until` functions but If I do that, my sub is really too long (I've more than 10 000 rows in my database).

### **TRY 1**

```
    ComboBox3.AddItem (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)), 0
    ComboBox3.List(iCount - 1, 0) = (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2))
    ComboBox3.List(iCount - 1, 1) = Round(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9), 2)
    ComboBox3.List(iCount - 1, 2) = (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1))
```

with this try, I will only add `(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2))` in the first row in the first column but how can I add the other columns like `Round(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9), 2)` & `(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1))` in the column 2 & 3. To sum up, how can I combine `.AddItem` and `.List`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA multi column listbox add item on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954954/excel-vba-multi-column-listbox-add-item-on-top)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.listbox.additem

Comment: @braX I surely can use the `.AddItem` parameter for my code but how can I use it with a multicolumn ComboBox like this? Indeed, If I write `.AddItem item, 0`, I need to specify the item but I add them after in my case.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean, but once the item is added, you can address that list item by index... the same way you are doing it.

Comment: `ComboBox3.List(ComboBox3.ListCount - 1, 0) = "Blah"`

Comment: @braX 'you can address that list item by index' how?

Comment: the same way you are already doing it... `ComboBox3.List(index, 0) = "test"`

Comment: `ComboBox3.List(index, 1) = "column 2"`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.listbox.list

Comment: `ComboBox3.AddItem item, 0` using this method it will add the item at the start but only in the first column, I think I misunderstand something. Look at my update on my post with the **TRY 1**.

Comment: I dont think you are paying attention to my comments... please re-read them - i dont see where you are getting `iCount` from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based the [braX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8422953/brax) comments here is a structured answer:

```
iCount = 1
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Range("A2").Select
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        If ActiveCell.Value = ComboBox1.Value And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17) <> "" Then
            ComboBox3.AddItem , 0
            ComboBox3.List(0, 0) = (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2))
            ComboBox3.List(0, 1) = Round(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9), 2)
            ComboBox3.List(0, 2) = (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1))
            iCount = iCount + 1
        End If
        If ActiveCell.Value = "ANY" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17) <> "" Then
            ComboBox3.AddItem
            ComboBox3.List(iCount - 1, 0) = (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2))
            iCount = iCount + 1
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End With
```

By doing this, all the specific rows will be added at the top of your `ComboBox3`.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
ComboBox3.AddItem ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2), 0
ComboBox3.List(0, 0) = (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2))
ComboBox3.List(0, 1) = Round(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9), 2)
ComboBox3.List(0, 2) = (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1))
```

Comment: I use a similar method, the first line can be modified such as: `ComboBox3.AddItem , 0`.